# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

Getting a `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async action` error:

Index Reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import ProfileReducer from './profile_reducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: ProfileReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Routes:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

const Routers = () => (
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} exact={true}/>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} exact={true}/>
        <Route path='/register' component={Login} exact={true}/>
        <PrivateRoute path='/profile' component={Profile} exact={true}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

export default Routers;

I am trying to run two request together: one request to get the auth_token from backend and upon the response of the first request i run another request to get user's profile information:

Profile Action:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { getAuthToken } from '../actions/auth';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1';
export const FETCH_PROFILE = 'fetch_profile';

export function getProfile(values, callback) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}/profile`;

  getAuthToken( (res) => {
    const auth_token = res.data.auth_token
    const request = axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Token token=${auth_token}`
      },
    });

    // request.then((response) => {
    //   // callback(response);
    // })
    // request.catch((error) => {
    //   alert(error);
    // })

    return {
      type: FETCH_PROFILE,
      payload: request
    };
  });
}
```

ho do i do it? what is the best way to do it and method?

Comment: You should add the code where you `dispatch` actions

Comment: I dont have any dispatch action! do i have to create a redux store for that?

Comment: In order to do anything async you need middleware like redux thunk https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: everytime i try to dispatch some function it says dispatch is not a function

Comment: @bilal You should probably head to a tutorial if you don't dispatch any actions, a good one : https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-redux-tutorial-beginners/

Comment: @FlorianF. i looked into it and amended my store according to it but i am still facing the same problem while doing 2 ajax request and one req is depending on the other request. i dont want to save the auth_token in redux store which i get from my first request. i just want to use the response auth_token to put in my second request and it works find till the end and then it says `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` i am not sure how to tackle it!

Comment: and if i do only one ajax request then it works fine and stores user info in store n all